# Reverse a password string and then for each character reversed display the previous letter in the alphabet

Tags: sql-server

We have an application that stores passwords in the following order in a database;
It reverse the original password that the user creates and increments the characters by 1. For instance if I choose a password - '**demo**' - the password will be stored as - '**pnfe**' -  I used reverse(*column*) and it reverses the *column* so instead of **demo** being stored as **pfne** it will now be stored as **enfp** where you can clearly see **enfp** is **demo** incremented with 1 character.

I recently started working at this company and by no means am I a programmer, but I like looking around the database tables and accidentally stumbled upon this table. The reason I want to be able to see the password when running a script or query is because the people here forget their passwords every other week, So we either have to reset the passwords or I normally try to work it out, which is a schlepp. Any help would be appreciated.

cheers
Jason

Comment: If you are trying to encrypt the data you can use other elegant way of encryption available in sql server

Comment: ... oh... oh my..  This might as well be plain text passwords.  Major no no.

Comment: Passwords should always be one-way!! No decryption should be possible; Your front-end must deal with this providing a way for users to reset passwords themselves by answering a few security questions

Comment: @KannanKandasamy We only support the system, the guys responsible for developing the software _to the best of my knowledge_ were a bunch of graduates. And as far as their experience go I have no idea. **techspider** I am also under the impression that that should be the case. I did make the recommendation to them to allow the users to be able to change their own passwords. Don't know if they are working on it, and we can't just leisurely speak to them because they charge per 15 minutes and we don't have a support contract with them so you can imagine the costs involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN has a good example of this. I modified it to take the previous ASCII value for what ever your DB has, in reverse, and return it.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#psswd') is not null drop table #psswd
create table #psswd (userid int, pswd varchar(40))
insert into #psswd (userid, pswd) values (1,'pnfe'), (2,'tofuujl')

DECLARE @userID int = 2


-- Create variables for the character string and for the current   
-- position in the string.  
DECLARE @position int
-- Initialize the current position and the string variables.  
SET @position = 1;  
WHILE @position <= DATALENGTH((SELECT pswd FROM #psswd WHERE userid = @userID))  
   BEGIN  
        SELECT CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(pswd), @position, 1)) - 1) FROM #psswd WHERE userid = @userID
   SET @position = @position + 1  
   END;  
GO
```

[Credit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177545.aspx)

Comment: Thank you the solution it works nice. One thing though, how do I work it so that when I run the script/query it will look at my login table and do the reversing on the password column instead of having to create a _tempdb_ every time I want to check a password for a user. `DECLARE @position int
DECLARE @userid int
  
SET @position = 1;

WHILE @position <= DATALENGTH((SELECT [password] FROM [MobileQualityDB].[dbo].[qmob_login] WHERE username = @userID))
BEGIN
  SELECT CHAR(((CAST([password] as int)))) FROM [MobileQualityDB].[dbo].[qmob_login]
  SET @position = @position
     END;
GO`

Comment: @JasonK  The temp table was just used to show you the results.  You can omit the first three lines and replace #psswd with what ever your table name is. Of course you need to change userid to whatever you are using to pull an employee, like their name or login ID or whatever.

Comment: @JasonK sorry only half the post showed up on my mobile. Change the last select to this: `SELECT CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([password]), @position, 1)) - 1) FROM [MobileQualityDB].[dbo].[qmob_login]  WHERE username = @userID`

Comment: `DECLARE @position int 
DECLARE @userid char(10) 
DECLARE @pswd char(10) 
SET @position = 1;
WHILE @position <= DATALENGTH((SELECT ((rtrim([password]))) FROM [MobileQualityDB].[dbo].[qmob_login] WHERE [username] = @userid)) 
BEGIN 
SELECT CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTRING(REVERSE((rtrim([password]))), @position, 1)) - 1) FROM [MobileQualityDB].[dbo].[qmob_login] WHERE [password] = @pswd
SET @position = @position + 1
END;
GO` That is what I got so far. When I run it it just show `Command(s) completed successfully.` Then when I give a value to `@userid` and `@pswd` it works. Thanks

Comment: No problem @JasonK